# Count each time a name is in a record as one instance

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I am new to Access and I have a table of patients where I have three different fields of tasks which can be completed by a nurse(their name goes in those fields). It's not always the same nurse performing the task but sometimes it is. I would like to get the total number of patients a nurse has seen without counting each interaction as a separate instance of contact.

Counting the total times a name appears in one column is easy enough. However, I want to count each record one time if a nurse's name is mentioned anywhere in those three fields no matter how many times the nurse's name appears.

It there a way to do this? I have been searching everywhere to find the answer to this question with no luck. Here is how the data appears. Each nurse comes from a drop-down box connected to another table.

```
Patient  Task1   Task2   Task3   Task4
Jones     Bill    Jack    Ruby    Bill
Smith     Ruby    Ivan    Raul    Ted
Barns     Ted     James   Rick    Ted
Jackson   Ted     Phil    Ruby    Bill
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You provide no information on data structures or sample data that could help anyone help you.

Comment: update your question and add  a proper data sample and the expected  result please

Comment: Sorry about that. I just added the sample data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You show 4 task fields, not 3.

One approach is to build a UNION query to reorganize the data to more normalized structure.

This UNION will prevent duplicate pairs of patient and nurse. It is possible to force the duplicate pairs by including a task identifier field or UNION ALL but you don't want them.

```
SELECT Patient, Task1 As Nurse FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Patient, Task2 FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Patient, Task3 FROM tablename
UNION SELECT Patient, Task4 FROM tablename;
```

Now use that UNION query in an aggregate (GROUP BY) query.